# Laravel 8 application return 404 Not Found

Tags: php, laravel, deployment

I have a Laravel 8 application that is properly running on a server. I have moved it to a different server but I am now getting a 404 Not Found on the new server. I have not changed anything on the new server so I believe it must an issue related to server. I am unable to diagnose the problem on the server. Details are some details about the app on the server:

**File Permissions respects the following**

```
chown -R apache.apache /var/www/LARAVEL_APP
chmod -R 755 /var/www/LARAVEL_APP
chmod -R 755 /var/www/LARAVEL_APP/storage
```

**Routes and Cache have been cleared using the following commands:**

```
php artisan route:clear
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```

**.htaccess file in LARAVEL-APP/public directory:**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>
   Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

When navigating to the root of the LARAVEL-APP, I can properly see the following screen. The problem occurs when I try to load the `index.html` located in `LARAVEL-APP/public/index.php/admin/login`
[image]

**Route List**

The list is available when doing `php artisan route:list | grep admin/login`

```
|        | POST                                   | admin/login                                           | generated::LTvCw5lDDMDMdfPT                        | Brackets\AdminAuth\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@login                                   | web                                                              |
|        | GET|HEAD                               | admin/login                                           | brackets/admin-auth::admin/login                   | Brackets\AdminAuth\Http\Controllers\Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm
```

**404 Screen**

Below is the 404 screen I am getting that seems to be from Laravel itself.
[image]

Comment: Can you turn on debugging mode in .env and see what is the error behind this 404 screen?

Comment: What server are you using? How is it set up? "_...home(/var/www/LARAVEL-APP)_" That's not an URL you could navigate to, and it is not "home". The `public` folder inside is "home". Does everything work when you use `php artisan serve` to serve your files?

Comment: @harunB10, i tried this, nothing is shown

Comment: @Noor you need to restart your server in order to see error messages.

Comment: @harunB10, I restarted, nothing is shown

Comment: @brombeer, the same problem in development mode

Comment: Can you post your `php artisan route:list` ?

Comment: @harunB10, updated the question, the route is well available

Answer (score 1):

try this code in .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

I hope this work for you.

Comment: check my .htaccess in the question, where do I put this line, after `RewriteEngine On` directly?

Comment: I mean, replace all the my codes with your own code in .htaccess file and check it is work or no.

Comment: this configuration is returning a 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: Now turn on debugging mode in .env and see what is the error behind this 500 screen? Please try clear all cache to effect the .env file in laravel appilication.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have not enabled `mod-rewrite`, try this:

```
sudo a2enmod rewrite
```

and also make sure you this in your apache conf:

```
<Directory "/var/www/">
    # ...
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

also restart apache after:

```
sudo service apache2 restart
```